# SugarCRM Database variable will not let me call the quote() function from my own property

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am building a SugarCRm Module.  It uses the old basic MySQL functions from like PHP4 days...

Most modules in the system access a Database wrapper class calling this Global variable and then using it.

```
global $db;

$db->quote($some_SQL_Query_To_Execute);
```

Now i'm not much of a fan of that so in my own custom Module classes in my Constructor method I am instead doing this...

```
class MyModuleClassHereForSODemo
{

    public $db;

    public function __cnstructor($id){

        $this->db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();

    }


    public function insertDBRecordFunctionHERE($id){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `db_table_name` (
        `topic_id`,
        `project_id`,
        `topic_subject`,
        `topic_content`,
        `date_created`,
        `date_last_post`,
        `created_by_user_id`,
        `last_post_user_id`,
        `posts_replies`
        ) VALUES(
            NULL,
        '$this->db->quote($project_id)',
        '$this->db->quote($topic_subject)',
        '$this->db->quote($topic_content)',
        UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
        UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
        '$this->db->quote($created_by_user_id)',
        '$this->db->quote($created_by_user_id)',
        '0');";

        $this->db->query($sql);

    }



}
```

Now here is the problem I am having, this SQL query above will not work because I am calling `$this->db->quote()` on my variables...now what is extremely weird and frustrating is if I instead use the GLOBAL $db variable, then I can run this instead `$db->quote()` and it works all day long...it;s as soon as I run the `quote()` method on my own classes $db property that it breaks everything.

Could this possibly be because the system is looking at them as being different connections to the DB even though it;s a Singleton and should be the same variable and object I would imagine....any ideas?

Also I don'tr have all the code for the DB class that I am accessing but I do know that the `quote` method is simply calling `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: What's the point of declaring your own instantiation of $db? $someModule->db already exists and is a module-specific reference to $GLOBALS['db'] but makes logging and resource monitoring easier. What are you trying to fix by doing this? Aside from all my questioning your reasoning - there's a typo in `__cnstructor` method that would prevent this from loading. Not sure if that's part of your original code or transposing, but would definitely prevent $db from being set since you're not extending SugarBean or some template that would normally set it.

Comment: @MatthewPoer it is a typo in this post and my class is not a bean model

Comment: What errors or warnings does it generate?

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party here but the issue isn't that you have a local `$db` variable. It's that string parsing wont pick up the use of functions in your string. You should use the complex syntax instead.

I.e.

```
$string = "This is a string with a function call'{$this->db->quote($project_id)}'";
```

See https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing